# Función Shell no funciona en Ubuntu 20.04/Tomcat9/Java11 para ejecutar script .sh

Tags: genexus, shell-script, genexus15, genexusxev3

Necesito ejecutar un bash script (.sh) desde una aplicación web hecha con Genexus X EV3 que genera sobre Tomcat9/Ubuntu 20.04/Java11 RE utilizando la funcion shell. El script contiene algo simple a manera de ejemplo, digamos esto:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir DirTest
```

La forma de ejecutarlo desde Genexus es

```
&path = '/home/adminap/tomcat9/webapps/proto01/test.sh'
&execute = shell(&path,1)
```

Sin embargo al momento de ejecutar el código anterior, dentro de un procedure de Genexus, no ejecuta el script y el valor que devuelve la función shell es 1, que denota que no se ejecutó.
No creo que sea asunto de permisos porque cuando desde la consola (Ubuntu 20.04) ejecuto el mismo bash script, con el usuario tomcat (el mismo que usa la aplicación en runtime), funciona.
Además cuando este mismo código

```
&path = '/home/adminap/tomcat9/webapps/proto01/test.sh'
&execute = shell(&path,1)
```

lo ejecuto en otro modelo de Genexus que genera para Tomcat7/Ubuntu 14/Java8, funciona perfectamente, es decir en Tomcat7 la funcion shell de Genexus trabaja bien pero en Tomcat9 ya no. Es el mismo generador y la misma KB solo cambia el ambiente a donde se genera. De antemano gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Ves algo en los logs de Tomcat?

Comment: Hola Alfabravo. Efectivamente revise los archivos catalina.2022-10-22.log y  localhost_access_log.2022-10-22.txt y no hay información relacionada con la ejecución de un bash script. O hay algo especifico que deba buscar alli ?

Comment: Mira el owner del arquivo (.sh)

Comment: Hola  Luis. Los permisos del bash script son:

`ls -lk test.sh`
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat 34 oct 21 15:31 test.sh`

El owner es el usuario tomcat, el mismo de Tomcat9 segun entiendo.

Comment: Finalmente encontré la solución a este issue en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74176190/genexus-shell-function-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-tomcat9-java11-to-execute/74185761#74185761). Saludos